# How to get user's profile picture on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I'm a bit new to using the Facebook API and I'm currently trying to query the API for the user's profile picture. I am using this access-token return to get the user information when he/she logs in:

```
//Next get the user id of the current user, which is unique and will be used in the database
$response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture&access_token=$accessToken");
$data = json_decode($response);
print_r($data);
```

This `print_r` outputs:

```
stdClass Object ( [
    id] => 0000000000000000 
    [name] => Username 
    [picture] => stdClass Object ( 
        [data] => stdClass Object ( 
            [is_silhouette] => [url] => valid_url )
    ) 
)
```

However, the picture is low-resolution and also 50x50. How can I get a higher quality image and a higher dimension? I couldn't find any information in the API. <strike>I read the API (which added to my confusion), and it first asked me to add a `redirect=false` in my query (it was using an `HTTP GET` method)</strike>

I can specify it correctly in the `http_get` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch image based on Facebook id of user and you can get every size of image like below example :

Large : https://graph.facebook.com/{facebookId}/picture?type=large

You can change type based on your requirement here is the some type normal,small,square.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom width and height for get any size profile picture by link http://graph.facebook.com/{facebook-user-id}/picture?width=1000&height=1000

and for type parameter you can use {small, normal, album, large, square}